# How to set up accuracy of edge length overlay?

Tags: 3d-view

Is there a way to somehow increase a number of digits in the fractional part of the edge length? For example, real length of the edge on the picture is 1.215mm. What can I do to make Blender display this length without rounding it off?

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the Length "Units" in the "Scene Properties" to "mm"? You can also activate "Separate Units" to have it display the next lower unit, like 102 mm and 32 μm.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I did that. When I switched to mm, I found out, that there is no fractional part at all, so I was unable able to distinguish (for example) 1225,1 mm from 1225,4 mm. I don`t need such an accuracy in my current project, but it is really strange for me, that in Blender it is impossible to set desired accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is not possible to increase the precision of the "Edge Length" overlay (as far as i know and after searching), there is a way to have a precise value displayed, **BUT** it's not "as easy" available and intuitive as activating the edge length.

What you may want to try is the "MeasureIT"-addon which comes with Blender.
[image]

It allows you to create a dynamic measurements.
I use **Segment** most the time to show the distance between 2 vertices (picture below).
[image]

As shown, the precision is set to 4 decimals after the point.

Expanding the shown measurement shows this:
[image]

Here you can deactivate it, change the color, size of the text, distance from object and many more things. Best to test and play around with to get the feel.

I hope it helps for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is impossible. The precision is hard-coded to 3 significant figures [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/draw/intern/draw_manager_text.c#L288).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the add-on *Edit Mesh Tools* and set the absolute value of the edge length.